# Need to code Manager and Employee classes. How do I make them "visible" to each other without breaking encapsulation?

Tags: java, inheritance, encapsulation

The Manager and the Employee classes are both subclasses of EnterpriseMember. How do I write a "getManager" method (that returns the Manager instance that has this Employee in their List of reports) for the Employee class?
Thanks in advance!

```
public class Manager extends EnterpriseMember {

    /*Fields */
    private List reports = new ArrayList();

    /*Constructor */
    public Manager(String name){
        super(name);
    }

    /*Methods */
    public void addReport(Employee employee){            
        reports.add(employee);
    }// How can "employee" know it is in this List?

}

public class Employee extends EnterpriseMember {

    /*Constructor */
    public Manager(String name){
        super(name);
    }

    /*Methods */
    public Manager getManager(){            
        return ???;
    }

}
```

Comment: You can't have a setManager(Manager manager) method in the employee class?

Comment: Your constructor for Employee should be public Employee(...) not public Manager(...)

Answer (score 3):

Something like this:

```
public class Manager {

    private List<Employee> reports = new ArrayList<Employee>();

    public void addReport(Employee e) {
        if (e != null) {
            this.reports.add(e);
            e.setManager(this);
        }
    }
}

public class Employee {

    private Manager manager;

    public void setManager(Manager m) {
        if (m != null) {
            this.manager = m;
        }
    }
}
```

Just in case it's not clear, you should add all the other methods you need.  I only illustrated how to update the `Manager` reference in `Employee` when it's added to the `List` of direct reports.

You should also have a `removeReport` method that removes an `Employee` from the `List` and sets its `Manager` to `null`.

How do you intend to find an `Employee` in this `List`?  By name?  Employee id?  Hint: think about overriding `equals` and `hashCode` properly for your classes.

Aren't `Managers` also `Employees`?  Don't bosses have bosses?  This is a hierarchy, a tree.

Answer (score 0):

Usually a Object with different Attributes looks like this:

```
public class Employee extends EnterpriseMember {

    private Manager manager;
    private String name; // You probably don't need this because you defined it in the Superclass.
    .
    .
    .

    /*Constructor */
    public Employee(String name){
        super(name);
    }

    /*Methods */
    public Manager getManager(){            
        return manager;
    }

    public void setManager(Manager manager){            
        this.manager = manager
    }

    // Other getters and setters for the attributes.

}
```